# How does WCF instancing affect the context in which methods are called?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, wcf, appdomain

WPF Instancing: when set to per-call, does a new "instance" get created under the same process as the service. Meaning that if the call runs out of memory it will crash the service as well?

Comment: Maybe it may crash - depends on your design. However, remember per-call instance means there is no state saved like per Session. WCF will smartly recycle existing instances to serve new requests.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how you are hosting the service.

If you are using IIS the instance exist in a worker process. If it crashes, it doesn't crash IIS.

If you are using self-hosting (Windows Service or other .NET process) you could crash the process.